# comparing two matrices with wilcoxon test

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have two matrices A and B of 2388 rows and 1001 columns. I would compare two matrices with `wilcox.test` but is not clear to me if I had:

1. directly input them ->

   `wilcox.test(mat_a, y =mat_b,alternative = c("greater"),paired = TRUE, conf.int=T)`
2. calculate the mean of each row and compare the two vectors:

   `A_mean= rowMeans(mat_a)`
   `B_mean= rowMeans(mat_b)`

`wilcox.test(A_mean, y =B_mean,alternative = c("greater"),paired = TRUE, conf.int=T)`

or do a wilcox.test for each row separately. This last one I don't think is what I need.
I just want to see if matrix A is more enriched than B

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "more enriched"?

Comment: You don’t want “paired =TRUE” in the first case since a and b are different populations.

Comment: @whuber in therms of chromatin enrichment. Each row Is a genomic region, each column Is a Cell and the values in the Matrix are numbers that indicate of many fragments there are in that Cell at a given region

Comment: Could you please add new information as an edit to the post, and not only as comments? We want posts to be self-contained, and comments are often seen only by a few people